# data segmentation time series

Tags: python, time-series, accelerometer

**How can I separate the sequences which represent important data from the unimportant ones?**

**Some** **background and an example:**
As it can be seen in the data plot (Figure), there are 9 segments in this time series, which was recorded with an IMU (measures acceleration – x,y,z, orientation rotation around x,y,z). The figure can be found below:

[image: Figure: Snipping gesture acceleration x,y,z]

the data on which the plot relies on: [Data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzdzx4krce2ytzd/GG_snip_before.csv?dl=0)

In this case, these represent a snipping movement from the right hand. Between each signal, there is a delay (2-3 seconds). This delay can also be extended.

**Which approach is the easiest to segment the data?** Where can I find examples for these, or could you give me a simple one? **What do I want to find out?: Where are the starting points of the relevant signals?**

- Anomaly detection. I already implemented this, but it predicts very vaguely (I haven't optimized it yet). Probably I need better features than only the raw data. I'm asking this question since there might be simpler methods.
- K-means clustering: I thought about this as well, but how do I approach this? Are there examples?
- Frequency domain analysis:
  Segment the raw data into frames (size 100) with an overlap and transform these into the frequency domain. Which features could I use? Thought about signal energy?
- other approaches?

Afterwards, these segments will be used as training examples for a gesture classifier.

[**Optional additional information: Recording environment:** Hand hangs loose -> gesture gets performed --> hand hangs loose --> wait for 5 Sec in the loose arm position --> [next iteration in recording a gesture].
Another important condition is also that I need to segment different kinds of gestures (the signals look different); not only a snipping gesture but also swipe up, swipe down, or thumbs up are possible.]

Thank you very much in advance :)

greets Max

Answer (score 2):

there is some possible solution with:
DBSCAN  [example here](https://github.com/choffstein/dbscan)
or
DTW [example here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dtw/1.0) methods.

Also, you can do it manually (for example Matlab m-file).
Here: axaR is your signal from accelerometer (along x-axis), k - number of points, threshold - manually adjutable value

```
figure (100)

for fig = 1: 5
k = 200;
threshold =20*fig*std(axaR);
fprintf('window size %d, threshold is %f\n', k,threshold)  
for i = 1: (length(axaR)-k)
    summa = 0;
    for j= 1:k
    summa =  summa + abs(axaR(i+j));
    end
    if (summa > threshold)
        c(i) = 1;
    else
        c(i) = 0;

    end
end

subplot(5,1,fig)
plot ( axaR, 'LineWidth', lw), hold on
plot(1:k,ones(k,1),'*r')
hold on, 
plot ( c, 'LineWidth', lw),
hold on, 
xlim([0,5000]),
title (strcat('threshold ', num2str(threshold), 'window size', num2str(k) ))
end
```

[Matlab figure that illustrates the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wJen.jpg)

This is the example from walking analysis, it is completely intuition based approach, please if you know any math or physics background, do not hesitate to share it.

Best

Comment: please may you deign to format your codes for readability sake next times using CTRL+G

Answer (score 1):

“How can I seperate the sequences which represent important data from the unimportant ones?”
Your question is ill-defined. What is “important” is subjective, and not intrinsic to the data.

However, if you want to build a classifier, you can reframe the question as “what is the best conserved subsequence?” . That you can answer with:

[matrixProfile, profileIndex, motifIndex, discordIndex] = interactiveMatrixProfileVer2( ay,250);   (the code is free at http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/MatrixProfile.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually segment data (supervised learning), I ran into the same problem so i created a simple python matplotlib library:
https://github.com/XavierTolza/python-timeseries-segmenter